# undefined return typescript function using .then()

Tags: typescript

Sorry I had no idea on how to write the title in a better way.

I currently have a typescript file with this function inside:

```
getCurrentPosition(){
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
        this.lat = Math.random()*10;
        this.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
        return {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
      });
    //   return {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}
}
```

if I call getCurrentPosition() I receive back an undefined value.
If I try to call it a second time after some time it return me a value (which was the one previously calculated)

How can I wait for the response of geolocation before returning any value?

Sorry for the dumb question, but I've spend way to much time on this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with TypeScript (I assume so since you mentioned Ionic), you can do something like this:

```
async getCurrentPosition(){
    const resp = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
    this.lat = Math.random()*10;
    this.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
    return {lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}
}
```

I am suggesting that you use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) ([tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions)) to simplify the Promise based async code.

The code snippet returns a Promise that resolves to `{lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng}`. By calling the function with `await getCurrentPosition()`, it will automatically resolve the promised value.

Can be a bit confusing initially once you get the idea, its awesome (checkout the tutorial link).

Comment: Thanks I was using the await in the wrong way.
I'll take a look into the tutorial since I'll need it again. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is because `getCurrentPosition()` is evaluating the `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method asynchronously, therefore the return statement is just executing immediately and returning an object with `lat` and `lng` in it which are undefined (If the commented out code is executed).

What you want to do instead is return `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` instead of simply executing it and setting properties on your class.

```
getCurrentPosition(){
    return this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(resp => {
        const lat = Math.random()*10;
        const lng = resp.coords.longitude;
        return {lat: lat, lng: lng}
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
      });
}
```

You can then simply execute it as follows:

```
getCurrentPosition()
    .then(response => {
        // response should equal {lat: xxx, lng: xxx}
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: The problem is that I have this method actually in a service (ionic provider) which is then imported and used.
That is why I need to use a function, geolocation is private thus I need a Get

I tried to use the async word before the get and when I cal the function use a then, but it did not worked

Comment: Does `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` return a promise then? And is `getCurrentPosition` a function you have defined?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/

Yes it returns a Promise<Geoposition>